# Java, null list

Tags: java

How can I verify if a List is null in Java ?

thanks

Comment: ... like `list == null`?

Comment: Do you mean 'null' or do you mean empty? Or do you mean 'contains only nulls'?

Comment: @DJClayworth I think the question is quite clear on that

Comment: I find it hard to believe that someone with so much reputation doesn't know how to do `if (list == null)`... but I find it interesting that most of Patrick's contributions have been answers to his own questions with no upvotes.

Comment: @Erick Robertson Yeah the first days I found out this trick

Comment: This isn't a "trick".  Comparing variables to `null` is a fundamental part of the Java language.

Comment: In fact you should upvote this answer because of his courage of posting such a stupid question...

Comment: Is there a Java FAQ on stackoverflow? Like the [C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) one.

Comment: The OP rep is 5K for god sake!.. is this a trick question?

Comment: He wasn't 5k when he posted this question was he?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By if condition:

```
if (list == null){
  // do something
}
```

Comment: +1 One of the easiest answers ever the get reputation for ;)

Answer (score 14):

```
List myList = getListFromSomeMethodThatMightReturnNullAlthoughItsBetterToReturnAnEmptyListThenYouWouldntHaveToDoAnyStupidNullChecking();

if (myList == null){

}
```

Answer (score 11):

A `List` instance can't be `null`, an instance is always *something*. A `List` type variable can be `null` and to test this, use the expression

```
 List<?> list = null;
 if (list == null) {System.out.println("I'm null");}
```

A `List` instance can by *empty*, meaning the list doesn't contain any values. To ways to test this:

```
 if (list.size() == 0) {...}     
 if (list.isEmpty()) {...}
```

A `List` instance can contain items that represent `null`. To find those, iterate through the list:

```
 for(Object o:list)
   if (o == null) {...}
```

Comment: ah crap ! that what I was going to answers. easy +1 for you :P

Answer (score 3):

If you have a variable myList of type `List`, you can do this by:

```
if(myList == null)
{
}
```

Comment: No, this won't compile in Java. Please, check out any of the other answers to the question.

Comment: I don't see why this is being downvoted; yes, "MyList" doesn't use standard Java naming conventions for variable names, but this is a perfectly valid boolean condition. I suppose if you think "MyList" is supposed to be a class name, as the capitalization suggests -- but I think from context it's clear that it's a variable.

Comment: @Tomas Narros:Woops, typo! lol I can't believe I actually wrote that wrong, I'm ashamed :p

Comment: I think the point was that the answer didn't make clear that this was a boolean condition in an if statement. You may think that's obvious, but if someone is asking how to test for null they need more detail in their answer.

Comment: `List` instances don't have names. Only `List` type variables can be named.